# How to run WordPress action

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system

I have defined action in `functions.php` like this:

```
add_action('pwr_search', 'pwr_search_function');

function pwr_search_function ()
{
    // do something
}
```

but how can I run this action throught url? This do not work:

```
http://my_wordpress/wp-admin/?action=pwr_search
```

Comment: What do you mean by "through URL" exactly, what is the context of this action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try hooking into the `init` action instead:

```
add_action('init', 'pwr_search_function');

function pwr_search_function ()
{

    if(isset($_GET['action']) && ($_GET['action'] === 'pwr_search')){

      // do something

    }
}
```

Also read about *[Actions Run During a Typical Request](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference)*.